# Why is my Core Graphics triangle being inverted when I draw it?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I am using the following code and it draws a triangle on the screen. But for some reason it displays the below triangle.

Here is the code:

```
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); 
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL,10.0f, 100.0f); 
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,100.0f,10.0f); 
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,100.0f,100.0f);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,100.0f,100.0f);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path); 
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor); 
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path); 
    CGContextFillPath(ctx); 


}
```

and here is the result:

```
      /|
     / |
    /  |
   /   |
  /    |
 /__ __|
```

But when I draw it on paper I came to this diagram:

```
   ___________
   \         | 
    \        | 
     \       |
      \      |
       \\     |
          \
            \|
```

(well you get the idea right)

What am I missing! Maybe I am not thinking straight. x is horizonal and y is vertical. (0,0) is the origin right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Y axis is flipped in the context you are drawing into. You can either adjust for that in your math or apply a affine transformation to flip it back

Comment: CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, flipVertical);

Comment: Thanks a million it worked! I am a complete newbie in IPhone so thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone, (0,0) is in the lower left corner: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-SW9

Comment: Yes! The picture that I am drawing also has (0,0) as the lower left corner.